# PHP Writing to file with HTML not working

Tags: php, html

I have been following a very basic example of a chat room that can be found [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application--net-5931).

When the user hits enter and POSTs the data, post.php is supposed to then write that text to the file log.html (which contains just log nothing else). 
I have 2 questions about this,

1. the first being **why do I need to POST the data to a different page and why cant I just write to the log file from index.php?** And
2. the second question being **Why is my post.php not writing to the log.html file?**

So far I have figured out that my index.php IS sending the POST request, but upon viewing the Developer Tools I can see that the response from post.php looks like this:

[image: this].

Why? Here is post.php:

```
$text = $_POST['text'];

$fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
$content = "<div class='msgln'>(".date("g:i A").") <b>".$_SESSION['name']."</b>:".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>";

fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
```

And the relevant part of index.php:

```
var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
$.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg});
$("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
```

Thanks for all of your help in advance!

Comment: *"And the relevant part of index.php:"* -- the posted code is Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: as a heads up - if usermsg is a text element, you can do `$('#textElement').val('');`

Comment: Can you show more of post.php and index.php? In the snipped you've given, there's nothing that would display the response you're seeing.

Comment: @thebluefox There is literally nothing else to add. `post.php` has an additional `html` and `body` tag and thats it, and `index.php`'s code is in a jQuery document ready function... thats all

Comment: *"There is literally nothing else to add"* ... if that's true then `post.php` should have a `<?php` opener before `$text` - you should *not* be seeing unprocessed PHP in your JS console; that implies it's not being interpreted.

Comment: @CD001 Yes there is a `<?php` before and a `?>` after.

Comment: And you're running this on a webserver (rather than `file:///`)? If your PHP was being processed the code would't be available for the JS console log.

Comment: Yes I am running it on the latest wampserver using localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the ***file permissions*** (chmod) have to be set in a way that the webserver is allowed to **write** to the log file. Secondly, you can send your data to the index.php, see example index.php below.

```
if(array_key_exists("text",$_POST) && $_POST["text"] != ""){
    //do log file writing
} else {
    //do your normal business
}
```

Comment: All this is doing is just checking that the user didnt send a blank string. My problem is the actual **writing** of the file.

Comment: As I have written, with the code above added to your ```index.php``` you can send your data to the index.php. Secondy, I have written in my answer that you should check file permissions!

Comment: At the beggining of `index.php` the PHP script writes to `log.html` with no problem. Its only when I send a POST request to `post.php` that the writing does not work.

Comment: Do you properly close the file after you write with the index.php?

Comment: If that means `fclose($fp):`  yes.

Comment: Seems really weird. Can you look in your webservers errorlog and check if anything corresponding to your problem is in there?
Can you comment out the line that defines the ```$content``` and add another line that says something like ```$content="hardcoded string message";```?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out where I went wrong. In post.php at the beginning of the file I had `<?` instead of `<?php` which is quite ironic because I double checked over that but did not think it mattered to much without the `php` bit.

Moral of the story: check **EVERY** bit of code, even if you've checked it before.